# Check if the provided fields are nil, Parse, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to make signup with parse, my code looks like this:

```
@IBAction func signUpTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
   let user = PFUser()

    // User details..
    // Profile picture..

        user.username = username.text
        user.password = password.text
        user.email = email.text

        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(dp.image!)
        let imageFile = PFFile(name: "file", data: imageData!)

        user["profile_picture"] = imageFile
        let fullName = fullname.text
        var myStringArr = fullName!.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

        user["first_name"] = myStringArr[0]
        user["last_name"] = myStringArr[1]

        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succes, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {

                print("error")

            } else {

                print("signedUp")

            }


        })


}
```

i want to show an alert if `username, password, email or fullname` is nil.
how can i make a check effectively with one line line of code instead of checking them separately..

i tried this too:

```
 if user.username == nil | user.email == nil | user.password == nil | user["first_name"] == nil | user["last_name"] == nil {     
    } else {

    }
```

but this is also giving me an error : `Expression was too complex to be solved.`

Thanks for your time.

Comment: fyi, a single | is a bitwise OR see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to check if username OR email etc is nil then you need to do it this way:

```
if user.username == nil || user.email == nil || user.password == nil || user["first_name"] == nil || user["last_name"] == nil {     
} else {

}
```

Notice that i'm using `||` instead of `|`